# How to determine which tables and stored procedures are not used by an ASP.NET web solution?

Tags: sql, asp.net, webforms, sql-server-2016, visual-studio-2019

I have a huge ASP.NET solution linked to a database with **109** tables & **213** stored procedures, but in fact the solution actually only uses a small number of these tables & stored procedures.

How can I know which tables and stored procedures are not used in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't going to be an automated way. You'll just have to search the files for the strings that correspond to the tables and sprocs. And make sure you're especially careful to look up anywhere that an identifier might be built up dynamically.

Hopefully you have automated testing in place to catch any place you break.